# How do I get a value back from a custom dojo module?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm working through the process of modulization on an app that I have written.  This works with spatial location

I'm using an event to query for the user's lat / lon position for use inside the application.  My calling snippet is below (button click starts it up)

```
<script>
    require([
        'dojo/dom',
        'dojo/_base/array',
        'demo/testModule',
        'esri/SpatialReference',
        'esri/geometry/Point'
    ], function (
        dom,
        arrayUtils,
        testModule,
        SpatialReference,
        Point
     ) {
        //Here is the button click listener
        $('#whereAmIButton').click(function () {
            var spatialRef = new esri.SpatialReference({ 'wkid': 4326 });

            //variable I want to set to a returned geometry.
            var myGeom;

            //This runs but I'm missing the boat on the return of a value
            testModule.findUserLocPT(spatialRef);

            //var myModule = new testModule(); //not a constructor
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the custom module.  It logs the information to the console for the user's location.  But I want to return the value for setting the 'myGeom' variable.

```
define(['dojo/_base/declare','dojo/_base/lang','dojo/dom',
'esri/geometry/Point','esri/SpatialReference'], function (
    declare, lang, dom, Point, SpatialReference) {
return {
    findUserLocPT: function (spatialRef) {
        var geom;
        var location_timeout = setTimeout("geolocFail()", 5000);
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            clearTimeout(location_timeout);

            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lon = position.coords.longitude;

            setTimeout(function () {
                geom = new Point(lon, lat, spatialRef);
                //console.log writes out the geom but that isnt what I am after
                console.log(geom);
                //I want to return this value
                return geom;
            }, 500);
        });
        function geolocFail() {
            console.log("GeoLocation Failure");
        }
    }
}//end of the return
```

});

Any help would be welcome.  I can by reference back change textual/html values on the document but am not getting things back as a variable.

Andy

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't know if this is the 'best' answer but I have one now.

I added a global variable inside the 'test.html' page

```
 <script>
    var theGeom;  //This is the variable
    require([
        'dojo/dom',
```

here is where I am setting the value of this variable for use in the original dojo 'require' code block.  This is coming from the 'testModule.js'

```
setTimeout(function () {
    geom = new Point(lon, lat, spatialRef);                                     
    theGeom = geom;    //Here is the feedback of the value to the global variable.                 
    return myGeom;
}, 500);


$('#whereAmIButton').click(function () {
    var spatialRef = new esri.SpatialReference({'wkid':4326});              
    testModule.findUserLocPT(spatialRef);               
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(theGeom);   //here is the value set and ready to use
            },2000);
});
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way.  If you have something better please let me know.

Andy